# (111) connection refused to localhost in jupyter notebook running on windows server 2012

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to use jupyter notebook in a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine. I have succesfully installed Anaconda 3 without problems. When running `jupyter notebook`from the anaconda prompt, in the comand line i see a message telling me the port 8888 is already in use, but that's no problem, it connects in the port 8889.

The connection via the anaconda propmt seems to work good, no error messages or weird things:

[image]

Then, the web browser opens and i get this message:

[image]

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance